# Move apps to the SD card and keep them there

Tags: app2sd

I have a phone with a very small internal memory (LG K7, just 4GB storage, running Android 5.1.1) but a nice roomy (64 GB) external SD card, so naturally I use an application manager (specifically, AppManager III) to move as many apps as possible to my external storage.  For the most part, it works fine.

But every time one of these apps updates the new version is (by default) installed in my internal storage, and I have to move it again.  This happens at least 2-3 times per week, especially for apps like Facebook, Twitter and Messenger, which update very, very frequently.

It's very frustrating to have to manually instruct my phone over and over again that, yes, I want to move the app to external storage *again*.  Is there a way to just set this once and forget about it?  One option, I guess, would be to turn off auto-updates.  But what I really want is a way to configure things so that the auto-updates are auto-moved to the external storage each time they are re-installed.  Particularly looking for methods that don't require rooting my phone.

Comment: There are many similar questions to read here and this really should be labelled a duplicate. This issue is unresolved over many years. Some background can be found through reading results of this [query](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=auto+update+SD+Card)